# Why I can't run JBoss EAP 6.2 server? It is automatically stopped

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6

I installed **JBoss EAP 6.1+** on my **Windows 8.1** system and it works fine.

Yesterday, suddenly it stopped working and give me the following error message when I try to run it (into Eclipse but also by the command line, so it is not an Eclipse configuration problem):

```
10:12:05,202 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final-redhat-2
10:12:05,765 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
10:12:06,028 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) starting
10:12:09,115 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) JBAS015005: Reliable deployment behaviour is not possible when auto-deployment of exploded content is enabled (i.e. deployment without use of ".dodeploy"' marker files). Configuration of auto-deployment of exploded content is not recommended in any situation where reliability is desired. Configuring the deployment scanner's auto-deploy-exploded setting to "false" is recommended.
10:12:09,173 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
10:12:09,201 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
10:12:09,212 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
10:12:09,264 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Remoting version 3.2.18.GA-redhat-1
10:12:09,459 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
10:12:09,489 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
10:12:09,495 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
10:12:09,510 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) JBAS012605: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main, 1.2]
10:12:09,594 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
10:12:09,716 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
10:12:09,738 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
10:12:09,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1
10:12:09,762 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.0.23.Final-redhat-1)
10:12:10,451 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
10:12:10,779 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
10:12:10,958 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
10:12:10,986 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
10:12:11,110 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/idesDS]
10:12:11,121 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/wifiDS]
10:12:11,632 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
10:12:11,698 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Program Files\EAP-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\deployments
10:12:11,843 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
10:12:11,862 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
10:12:12,212 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.3.Final-redhat-1
10:12:12,386 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014647: Could not rename C:\Program Files\EAP-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\configuration\standalone_xml_history\current to C:\Program Files\EAP-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\configuration\standalone_xml_history\20151106-101212372
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFile.createHistoryDirectory(ConfigurationFile.java:474) [jboss-as-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFile.successfulBoot(ConfigurationFile.java:306) [jboss-as-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.BackupXmlConfigurationPersister.successfulBoot(BackupXmlConfigurationPersister.java:65) [jboss-as-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.finishBoot(AbstractControllerService.java:308) [jboss-as-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:326) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:253) [jboss-as-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]

10:12:12,390 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
10:12:12,438 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/wifiDS]
10:12:12,486 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/idesDS]
10:12:12,488 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
10:12:12,563 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWEB003075: Coyote HTTP/1.1 pausing on: http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
10:12:12,574 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWEB003077: Coyote HTTP/1.1 stopping on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
10:12:12,627 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB001079: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/] has not been started
10:12:12,680 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015950: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) stopped in 243ms
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

So what could be the problem? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

To be short, relevant error message:

> Caught exception during boot: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   JBAS014647: Could not rename C:\Program
>   Files\EAP-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\configuration\standalone_xml_history\current
>   to C:\Program
>   Files\EAP-6.2.0\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\configuration\standalone_xml_history\20151106-101212372

It would sound like a directory or a file in that directory is locked by some software instance.

So check if you don't have your configuration files open in any editor, cmd line instance or some other process. If else fails, reboot your computer.

Comment: No I have not and I have rebotted my computer several times...could be some file permission problem?

Comment: it's possible. If you don't have anything you want to save there, you could delete previous history files manually and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: also, why do you have eap 6.2 on the subject but 6.1 on the question? which is it or did you change it?